# Simulation examples on SOFA framework with haptics force feedback

Tags: c++

For last two weeks I was trying to build SOFA framework and run some examples, with  haptics force feedback, from this directory ../plugins/Sensable/examples/Denistry/.

But unfortunately I can not succeed to run it properly, because runSofa.exe  stops running, when I open any of those .scn files from the directory mentioned above. I followed all the instructions to build and run from official site (https://www.sofa-framework.org/community/doc)

What I did is :

- downloaded 16.08 branch sources from https://github.com/sofa-framework/sofa
- configured and generated Visual Studio win32 project by CMake
- built release sofaRun and sensable plugin
- errors occurred in senable project, especially NewOmniDriver.cpp and OmniDrivver.cpp files. I added sofa::helper namespace [adding_sofa_helper][1]

  then it compiled without errors

I am hoping to find anyone who was able to run or build simulations with haptics force feedback and want to understand what I am doing wrong. If you need more explanation about what exactly I did, I will provide it. I will appreciate any response related to this topic.

Comment: I have succeed on running examples with haptic feedback using sensable plugin. The sofa developers are still updating the sources of the framework. So I checked the master branch of their repository and build that sources. After that the examples with haptic feedback worked as it suppose to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeed on running examples with haptic feedback using sensable plugin. The sofa developers are still updating the sources of the framework. So I checked the master branch of their repository and build that sources. After that the examples with haptic feedback worked as it suppose to do. – Ruslan Rakhmatov just now